# Cannot Open the Word files in OneDrive after copying from Google drive using Azure Logic App

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

**I want to copy the files from Google Drive folder to One Drive Folder using Azure Logic Apps.**

The **workflow** I have created is below:

[image]

I can see the each step is successful but If I open One Drive Folder and see the files:

[image]

**Note**:

1. Same Word File I'm able to see clearly and edit in Google docs. File doesn't have any errors.
2. The Workflow is still in running state. Unable to cancel even after each step is successful. Does it mean, taking the time in copying the files where files are not more than a MB Size (Around 300 KB Sized, contains text and pictures in the word file).

**Did I miss any step in the workflow like any conversions required or other because not sure the extensions of the word files saved in Google drives and OneDrive's..?**

**Google Drive Docs View**:

[image]