# Conversion of .gdoc files into .docx files in Azure Logic App

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

Continuous to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76070755/cannot-open-the-word-files-in-onedrive-after-copying-from-google-drive-using-azu), I stuck at the step of converting the Google Drive word files to Microsoft Word files i.e., `.gdoc` file extension to `.docx` file extension.

In UI Perspective, we have a option to download the Google Docs (word) files in terms of the formats we needed as shown in this [reference](https://howdoi.daemen.edu/knowledge-base/how-to-save-a-google-doc-as-a-word-file/).

[image]

[image]

I'm able to list files from the folder or get file content using path. But I stuck at the step of converting that gdoc files into Onedrive word files (.docx extension) using Azure Logic App.

I didn't find the suitable connector to achieve it or if this is possible using custom connectors or logic, I'm new to Azure So.

Could anyone assist me in achieving this..!:-)

Comment: Maybe look at using this REST API … https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export#http-request

Comment: Thanks @Skin. Could you please show a workflow example of using this rest api on above scenario.

Comment: Nope, sorry, it's not that simple from LogicApps because it appears as though you need a Workspace account to perform the integration.  I could be wrong but that's how it appears to me.  I'm trying to use a service account but having problems and it looks like that's why.  I managed to run the API in the test console and it looks like it works.